# Plone Migrate Blob Data to "bushy" layout IOError Errno 21

Tags: python, plone, zodb

I am trying to migrate our blobstorage (using Plone 4.3.2 and ZODB3 3.10.5) from 'lawn' to 'bushy' layout. While running the script, I get the following traceback:

```
(11719) Blob directory `var/blobstorage-lawn/` has layout marker set. Selected `lawn` layout.
(11719) The `lawn` blob directory layout is deprecated due to scalability issues on some file systems, please consider migrating to the `bushy` layout.
Migrating blob data from `var/blobstorage-lawn/` (lawn) to `var/blobstorage` (bushy)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/migrateblobs", line 19, in <module>
    sys.exit(ZODB.scripts.migrateblobs.main())
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43_dev/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-linux- x86_64.egg/ZODB/scripts/migrateblobs.py", line 77, in main
    migrate(source, dest, options.layout)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43_dev/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/ZODB/scripts/migrateblobs.py", line 52, in migrate
    link_or_copy(source_file, dest_file)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43_dev/buildout-cache/eggs/ZODB3-3.10.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/ZODB/scripts/migrateblobs.py", line 30, in link_or_copy
    shutil.copy(f1, f2)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43_dev/Python-2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 119, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "/var/db/zope/plone43_dev/Python-2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/var/db/zope/plone43_dev/zeocluster/var/blobstorage-lawn/0x00/0x00'
```

I don't understand why it is trying to copy a directory. Is this a bug in the product? Or could my blobstorage be corrupt? It is a dev environment, and I have been having some other issues with the blobstorage, which is why I'm trying to migrate to bushy in hopes that it will resolve some issues.

Thoughts or solutions?

Comment: What product/script you are using for the migration?

Comment: @keul: the [`migrateblobs` script](https://github.com/zopefoundation/ZODB/blob/master/src/ZODB/scripts/migrateblobs.py) that comes with ZODB. That much is clear from the traceback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You appear to have a *bushy* layout intermixed with your *lawn* layout.

The *lawn* layout uses a flat structure; directories are named after the OID, with in each directory *just* the revisions of the blob files. The *bushy* layout uses one directory *per byte in the OID*, leading to a tree of directories.

When moving from *lawn* to *bushy* the script takes *directories* assuming they are valid OIDs, and on each assumes that all it'll find in the directory is revision files.

You, however, already have a *bushy* layout structure. The script is trying to move the directory `0x00` out of a top-level directory `0x00`. That's exactly the kind of directories you'd find in a *bushy* layout, not a *lawn* layout. Your structure is corrupted indeed.

It may be that all that is wrong is the marker file; if all you have at the top level are `0xhh` 2 digit hex numbered directories, then you have *just* a *bushy* layout disguised as a *lawn*. You can then try changing the `.layout` file in the `var/blobstorage-lawn` directory from `lawn` to `bushy` and see if your ZODB still works. If not, it probably is beyond repair.

If you have a mix of `0xhh` and longer `0xhhhhhhhhh` hex directories (the latter only containing files, no directories) then you managed to put both a *lawn* and a *bushy* layout into the one blob storage. If the layout is marked as *lawn*, the *bushy* part is most likely out of date. You can try and move all directories with just 2 hex digits out to a new `blobstorage` directory (and add a new `.layout` file with the content `bushy` to it), but I am not too confident that anything useful is contained in it.

Comment: I see what you mean. There is only the one directory `0x00` with that format, all of the others are the longer hex format. I changed the .layout to `bushy` and was able to start the site up without error or warning. This might be unrelated, but I am having an issue with blob-type content not finding the blobs. Getting error `POSKeyError: 'No blob file'` when trying to view an image or file that has been migrated. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: The one top-lever dir with `0x00` just indicates your object ids haven't reached all that far yet; you'd only get `0x01` when you get a large number of objects (e.g. after years of transactions sometimes). If you get `POSKeyError`s then your bushy-lawn franken-monster was probably really a lawn layout with an accidental bushy copy super-imposed. Move back to lawn, *remove* the `0x00` top-level dir and migrate the rest.